# How can I change the Body of a post request in Postman?

Tags: javascript, axios, postman, twitch-api

I'm able to get the property (URL, which responds with the URL to an image) I need for my application, but I need the image in a larger size.

[image: 't_thumb' is interchangeable. I want that to be 't_1080p']

't_thumb' is interchangeable. I want that to be 't_1080p'. By changing that, the responded data would be a URL with a large image.

When I make the post request, it will always retrieve the URL with 't_thumb', but I would prefer that part of the URL to be 't_1080p', or another variable.

How can I do this?

I've tried looking at documentation, but haven't had much luck. A user on the API's message board suggested: "You need to manually find/replace on the URL string.", however, this doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting images using the API returns a default image url using the t_thumb format. To request larger image sizes you should manually create your own image url using the image_id and the appropriate image size. example: [https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_{size}/{image_id}.png](https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_%7Bsize%7D/%7Bimage_id%7D.png)

More information about images and image sizes can be found in our documentation, [here](https://api-docs.igdb.com/#images)

Comment: Thank you. I ended up just returning the URL, but using the JavaScript's .replace() function.